# How do I control the media keys of my Mac with my own program?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I would like to write a program that controls the media buttons. Or their function: volume up / down, next, previous, mute, play / pause

where can I find something about it?

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?SoundVolume) should help you with the volume control, as for the play/pause/forward/previous, you might look into just executing an applescript script to do those things.

Hope this helps